# Cannot find class in the Manifest though it is declared

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using the new Google Places SDK and my embedded fragment it is requiring me to declare the AutocompleteActivity

Here is the error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.activehours.debug/com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

My manifest:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.activehours"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="9.1"
>
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="${AppIcon}"
    android:roundIcon="${AppIconRound}"
    android:label="${AppName}"
    android:name=".core.ActiveHours"
    android:theme="@style/AHTheme"
    >
    ...
        <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity"
        android:theme="@style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay">
    </activity>

   ...
</application>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: i think it has to do with the fact that its searching for com.activehours.debug/com.google...... not for com.google.android.....

Comment: Not sure if it is what you want. But have you tried the Autocomplete.IntentBuilder using AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN? [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)

Comment: I had the same error when I refactored my package name. re-syncing my grade did the trick for me. Try making a small change in the gradle.build file, then click sync.

Comment: I am also facing the exact problem.. @Kristy Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @AninditaPani   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124792253

Comment: @KristyWelsh have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the documentation

> Caution: Do NOT launch the AutcompleteActivity directly. Instead, use an intent to launch Autocomplete (PlaceAutocomplete in the compatibility library).

You are not supposed to declare this as an activity in your manifest. Just send an intent to start the AutoCompleteActivity and listen for the results in the onActivityResult callback.